# Meaning and examples of "new (expr-list) type" operation

Tags: c++, new-operator

In “The C++ Programming Language” book, in list of operations *(article 6.2)*, Bjarne Stoustrup wrote this:

> **create (place)** new ( expr-list ) type
>
> **create (place and initialize)** new ( expr-list ) type ( expr-list )

I’ve never heard about this kind of the `new` operator, and I’m interested what does it do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called placement-new. You can create an object over already existing memory.

Here's an [explanation](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/placement-new.html) and an useful [question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new)

You can also have `nothrow`, for example:

```
char* pzNewBuffer = new (nothrow) char [2048];
```

which tells, that `new` will not throw `std::bad_alloc` in case of out of memory, but it will return `NULL`, instead.

---

Another example, that comes to my mind - the standard containers (probably) use `placement new`: when you call `reserve`, memory is allocated, but nothing is constructed/initialzed on this memory. So, when you insert (with `std::vector<T>::push_back` for example), if there's allocated, but not initialized memory - `placement new` is used.

Answer (score 1):

It does what you tell it to do. Some people use it to pass an allocator environment and alignments. For example in a language runtime I wrote I do

```
new (myEnvironment) Variable(initialValue);
```

The clang compiler associates allocated AST resources with an "ast context", so it does something like

```
new (AstContext, 32 /* alignment */) MyFooBar;
```

The arguments are all passed as a single argument list to an overloaded `operator new`, with the size requested as a first argument prefixed before them.